# Proving that a function has a maximizer

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

I am trying to prove this:

Let $X$ be a nonempty, convex, and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a concave function. Then $f$ has a maximizer.

Now this is trivial (somewhat) if f is continuous because of Weistrass' theorem. But f isn't necessarily continuous here.

I have been stuck on this for a couple of days now. I can sort of imagine why this would be true if $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. But I haven't gotten any idea further than that yet.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Isn't a concave function necessarily continuous?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I thought that that was only the case if it was defined on an open set. Otherwise, in a compact set for instance, you could have a boundary point at which the function is discontinuous but still retains its concavity.
correct me if Im wrong

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely. You are completely right. The function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} -x^2, & |x|<1, \\ -2, & |x|=1,\end{cases}$$ is concave.

Comment: A concave function is continuous _on the interior of its domain_.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. For (my) convenience, I answer the equivalent question of the existence of a minimizer of a convex function.

Let $X = [0,1]$ and
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{for } x \in (0,1], \\ 1 &\text{for } x = 0. \end{cases}$$
Then, $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in X$ and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \searrow 0$. Hence, $f$ does not possess a minimizer on $X$.

Comment: This seems embarassingly simple, now. Thank you. And if you dont mind me asking, is there much of a difference between asking whether a maximizer exists and whether the arg max of the function is non-empty?

Comment: No, this is essentially the same question.

Answer (score 0):

As @gerw already answered, the claim is not true. I'd like to add that there is a little additional assumption which will lead to a true statement:

> A concave and *upper semi-continuos* function on a convex and compact domain has a maximizer.

Comment: In this statement you can even drop 'concave' and 'convex'. The semi-continuity assumption and compactness is enough.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course!